# Drain pan getting water from bottom of evaporator leak?

Tags: air-conditioning

I have a typical "split system", with the evaporator/furnace unit in the attic and compressor on the outside.  The evaporator has two drain lines.  The primary drains to a bathroom sink trap and the secondary drains to the outside.  I noticed water dripping from the outside drain.  Since this is a newly installed unit I thought something wasnt right.  Sure enough the primary line had some crud in it.  Clished it out with a hose and it drains.

However, I was still seeing water in the pan and dripping from the outside drain.  While in the attic, I noticed water dripping from the bottom of the unit.  Is this normal or should all drainage be going through the pipe and into the primary drain line?  See arrow in photo, this is where I was seeing dripping from - and into the pan just below.

[image]

Comment: I can’t tell from the photo but you may need to add an algicide/ sanitizer  type tablet to keep your lines clear, it is great your hvac guy set you up with dual drain zones but I can’t tell from the photo enough to answer your question but can say gunkies grow with the right conditions tablets placed in the trays and or UV lamp light can help kill the gunkies and keep the home air cleaner and safe.

Comment: Yes, there was sediment in the primary drain line.  However I dragged a hose with a high-pressure nozzle up there and flushed it good.  My son who I had stay near the sink and we both had our phones on speaker, could both hear the water gushing into the drain.  What your seeing in the photo where the arrow points is the bottom of the unit.  If water is dripping from here, that is what is filling the pan.  So either something isnt draining right into the primary drain or the primary drain is still clogged.  However, the primary drain seems clear to me.